# slf4j and log4j logging file is not appending

Tags: java, logging, log4j, slf4j

I have a problem with slf4j and log4j.. I can see the log messages in the console but those messages are not appending to the file

i am using the following jars.

```
slf4j-log4j12-1.7.5.jar
slf4j-api-1.7.1.jar
log4j-1.2.17.jar
```

My log4j.properties file is below.

```
    # Root logger option
    log4j.rootLogger=INFO, file

    # Direct log messages to a log file
    log4j.appender.file=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
    log4j.appender.file.File=C:\\myLogFile.log
    log4j.appender.file.MaxFileSize=1MB
    log4j.appender.file.MaxBackupIndex=1
    log4j.appender.file.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
    log4j.appender.file.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss}
 %-5p %c{1}:%L - %m%n
```

and I am getting the following warning in console when i am running my java class

```
SLF4J: Class path contains multiple SLF4J bindings.
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/C:/Users/1018835/.m2/repository/ch/qos/logback/logback-classic/1.0.10/logback-classic-1.0.10.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/C:/Users/1018835/.m2/repository/org/slf4j/slf4j-log4j12/1.7.5/slf4j-log4j12-1.7.5.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#multiple_bindings for an explanation.
SLF4J: Actual binding is of type [ch.qos.logback.classic.util.ContextSelectorStaticBinder]
```

can any one help me on this? thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use `log4j` then keep this binding only. Remove `logback-classic-1.0.10.jar` from your `classpath`. As the log is telling that there are `multiple bindings in your classpath`.

This is excerpt from [slf4j site](http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#multiple_bindings):

**SLF4J API** is designed to bind with one and only one underlying logging framework at a time. If more than one binding is present on the class path, SLF4J will emit a warning, listing the location of those bindings.

When multiple bindings are available on the class path, select one and only one binding you wish to use, and remove the other bindings. For example, if you have both slf4j-simple-1.7.7.jar and slf4j-nop-1.7.7.jar on the class path and you wish to use the nop (no-operation) binding, then remove slf4j-simple-1.7.7.jar from the class path.

Comment: Thanks for the response @Sanjeev can i disable that binding with out removing the logback-classic-1.0.10.jar

Comment: @PrabhakarManthena No Sir, As mentioned above you have to remove other binding in order to make it work. You can visit the link in answer for more details.

Comment: but im using dropwizard for the rest api so logback-classic-1.0.10.jar is required for dropwizard framework thats why i can not remove that logback-classic-1.0.10.jar

Comment: In that case one way is to change your logging framework from slf4j to direct log4j.

Comment: can i exclude the implementation of the slf4j in logback-classic-1.0.10.jar in maven build ??

Comment: This is a runtime problem as you said you need this jar for some other api to work

Comment: or other way to may be use lagback as logging platform instead log4j